# Uploading xamarin.iOS app to app store connect failed

Tags: xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

I've been trying to upload my xamarin.iOS app to app-store-connect several times during the past couple of days. I have been using Visual Studio for Mac's Sign and Distribute window to upload the app to app-store-connect without any issue, until a couple of months back.

Checking my network activity, it shows that the app is being uploaded. So I have waited for more than 3 hours, but the app distribution window didn't show any response.
This has been happening for the past couple of months and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Then I used the Transporter app to upload the app, and it also didn't go well. (Check the error logs)

```
An exception has occurred: java.net.UnknownHostException: contentdelivery02.itunes.apple.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

An exception has occurred: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: contentdelivery02.itunes.apple.com:443 failed to respond

java.net.UnknownHostException: contentdelivery02.itunes.apple.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: contentdelivery02.itunes.apple.com:443 failed to respond
```

For me, it looks like there is an issue with the Apple servers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: @Jason I have checked that too, but all the system were available

Comment: It's  Apple server problem ,  try to upload your app in another network , also seek better support on Apple forum : https://developer.apple.com/forums/ .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT what did you mean by "another network"?

Comment: I mean you can choose another network to upload your app .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I will try next time. thanks